# Can I get the virtual directory (if there is one) with the $_SERVER variable?

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to have one way of creating dynamic URL's that works in development *and* production. Right now I'm building the URL's like this:

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/contact.php?failed");
```

but the problem with this is that I currently run the site like this off my WAMP server:

```
http://localhost/vdname/contact.php
```

and so that line of code doesn't generate the right URL in development - it builds:

```
http://localhost/contact.php?failed
```

instead and thus I get an expected `404`. How can I build the URL's properly so that they work in both development *and* production?

## EDIT

Per a number of suggestions, it would better to leverage `VirtualHost` entries in the `httpd.conf` file for this so I could use a normal domain name locally. So, I'm trying to get that to work and it's not working like I want, consider this code from the conf:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example
    ServerName local.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and the associated `hosts` file configuration:

```
127.0.0.1       local.example.com
```

but when I navigate to `http://local.example.com/contact.php` I get a `403 Forbidden` and when I run an `nslookup local.example.com` I don't get `127.0.0.1` either.

Comment: I doubt there is a `/` in any requesting `host`, as that would be against the HTTP specs. Most likely, you get redirected to `http://localhost/contact.php?failed`, but _something else_ is then redirecting yet again to `http://localhost/vdname/contact.php?failed`. Open a debug network log in the browser of your choice & check this. If the _first_ redirect is already to with the `/vdname` part attached, I would bet good money some of your code is altering `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` by accident, maybe by using `.=` somewhere where `.` should be used.

Comment: BTW: you are quoting a portion of `REMOTE_HOST` (which is not what you want, you are using the corret `HTTP_HOST`: _"Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one."_)

Comment: @Wrikken, noted and fixed. Also, I did what you stated and as you expected - it's not providing two different values. So, let me ask this, is there a way for me to get the virtual directory (if there is one) so that the code works on my development box as well as the production servers?

Comment: _'virtual directory'_ here is somewhat ambiguous... You mean you develop in `http://localhost/somedir/` & then go live on the root of `http://www.example.com/`? I'd do myself a favor in that case: define a `sometestsite.local` domain in my hosts file, set it up in apache as such, and that way I'm always a 100% sure the paths stay the same overall.

Comment: @Wrikken, that's a fantastic idea! Can you add that as an answer, with a short example for me (I'm real new to PHP and APACHE - I come from IIS and .NET) and I'll mark that as the answer and +1 my friend!

Comment: Please rewrite that question. Ignoring all the parts that are crossed out leaves us with a question with no context. Please remove the irrelevant parts and write one coherent question.

Comment: If you're using the same code in both places whether it's on a dev server or not, the only code you can alter without potentially breaking the site would be CSS and HTML interfaces that weren't commonly shared. Anything broken in the dev environment would show up on production immediately if you're sharing the same server-side code.

Comment: You probaby need to add a `<Directory /www/example>                Order allow,deny allow from all</Directory>` in that vhost (though the error log may tell more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my stuff I use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Because the `HTTP_HOST` is pulled from the HTTP request header and it is client set. If someone hits your site from www.yoursite.com and yoursite.com you might actually have two different results for `HTTP_HOST` in the same session. This can play havoc with cookies and redirects, not to mention with your site in terms of SEO and traffic patterns.

To stay on the same site, rather than populating the `header()` location command with an offsite URL (containing HTTP), you can use this instead:

```
header("Location: /contact.php?failed");
```

Also in your form you can use this:

```
<form action="/gdform.php" method="post" style="float: left;">
```

By using that style of links the browser will stay on the same site without performing a look-up (DNS) and it will stay in the same SubDNS.

You would need to make sure that `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` was properly configured in Apache, assuming that's what you're running.

Comment: Then again, if you have multiple sites in 1 codebase which just runs on a single docroot and just switches some css & database-queries based on hostname... HTTP_HOST would be exactly what you want. SERVER_NAME / HTTP_HOST each have their advantages & drawbacks.

Comment: @Wrikken it would be better to setup multiple virtual hosts in the Apache config and allow it to handle all of the header requests via server config than trying to recreate the server config in the .htaccess file though. You would then place all of the code below the root and then access the shared code with includes via both sites without an issue using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].` All web files would of course be in their respective web root folders.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ, I'm trying to get a virtual host to work in Apache and it's not working like I wanted, let me edit my question to show you how I'm configuring it.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ, please see my edit surrounding the `VirtualHost`.